# How to ensure that table was not tampered with in the SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, security

I need simple but reliable mechanism to ensure that table was not tampered with in the SQL Server 2008. The assumption is that hacker can access and control only one of the servers (application or database) but cannot access both. Any links or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Clarification. "Tampering" here means ability to update/delete row after it was inserted into the table. Table to be protected is a sort of business transaction log.

Comment: Exactly what would you consider "tampering" that could be differentiated from normal usage?

Comment: I have added clirification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go over the top, I'd suggest the following:

- Disallow any direct write access to the table.  Don't allow updates at all, inserts are performed via a stored procedure.
- Part of the log data is an MD5 checksum of the fields (not including the record ID).
- After the log is written, send the record ID and checksum to an external logging server.  Do this via a TCP broadcast.  That way, even if the intruder knows data is going to an external machine, they won't know which one (or how many).  The logging server simply records the record IDs and checksums, no updates or modifications are permitted.  Receiving a duplicate ID should result in an alarm being raised.  You might also want to verify that the record IDs are received in a monotonically increasing sequence, but that's likely to cause problems in a high-throughput environment.

Answer (score 4):

Your time would be better spent ensuring that a hacker can't get in at all, because as soon as you start making pessimistic assumptions like above, then you can be sure that a hacker *Will* get into both servers.

You could create an audit system via triggers that makes log entires anytime someone does an insert/update/delete to a table/tables on your DB Server, but this doesn't stop a hacker who's gained SA access from just nuking your audit tables or master DB.

Concentrate on Security, putting good code in place to prevent SQL Injection Attacks, Making sure you use SQL Login Accounts in your application with only the permissions they need, ensuring your database is behind a DMZ and not publically accessible, proper firewall and port security on the outside to ensure that only your Web/Public facing service ports are open.

If this is for a production environment and is beyond your expertise, there are security companies who will analyse you applications for any vulneribilities as well

Comment: Let say "hacker" has legitimate access to the server. "Nuking" log or master db is enough indication that database was tampered with :)

Comment: If your hacker has legitimate access (lets not sugar coat, maybe a disgruntled employee decides to f**k things up) then you have very serious trust issues with the people you're allowing on the box.

But if its purely for audit reasons to track accidental changes, then an audit system that logs inserst/updates/deletes based on triggers on your source table is probably  the best bet

Comment: @Eoin Yes, we do have trust issues with people using the system in the field, that's why we need to build the system that "requires two people to commit a crime". One person can access app.server, the second person can access the database.

Answer (score 1):

If your only purpose is to be able to validate the contents of your business transaction log table, you could store a hash value (MD5 or SHA) in, say, an XML file on the application server. When the application adds a transaction to the database, add a hash value to the XML file. You could then audit the data in the table by ensuring that...

- The number of elements in the file and the number of rows in the table match
- For each row in the table the computed hash value (however you define this) matches the value stored in the file for that row

Answer (score 0):

Put a DDL trigger on the database to monitor any changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

What about access logs? You can probably see if your user changed something in the database or web application user did this. Then again, how do you differentiate between normal and abnormal activities from your web application user?

Comment: I have edited the question to add clarification. I do not care if hacker controlling web server will generate invalid transactions, he shouldn't be able to alter business transaction log.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure you server is properly locked down is obviously the first thing you should do.

A possible solution to catch mistaken edits is that you could compute a checksum of some sort on all the fields in a row, and store that in the row as a long, unintelligible string; If a stored procedure did the insert/update commands, it could re-compute that checksum at each insert/update. If someone directly edited the data, i.e. thru Access or Management studio and directly edited fields, the checksum would be off and on the next access you could detect that and take action.

Of course if someone has access to the SP, then a motivated hacker will just duplicate the logic (or else just use the SP), but it would likely deter and catch sloppy direct edit mistakes made by people who are not malicious, but are accidentally editing data they shouldn't.

Comment: Hmm... So what if we move the logic from SP to application server? Hacker will have only one piece of puzzle as he cannot access both servers.

Comment: Thats fine too...have the  appp server compute the checksum on each save/update, if direct edits are done to the underlying table the checksums won't match. Its not bullet-proof, but it goes a long way towards ensuring that updates are only done thru the app server.

Comment: Though this will not, unfortunately, deal with any DELETED records, only updated ones.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use stored procs and nodynamic sql, you can set permissions at the proc level instead of the table level. This protects you from ever having a hacker do anything except what the application will allow. No one except the dbas should have any acces to tables in production.

Next, set up audit tables to record all changes to the data and when they happend and who made them. This can be used to easily get the data back if someone makes unauthorized changes.

Third, make sure you have a good backup plan running and backup your transactions logs every 15 minutes. Make sure your dbas have practice restoring from backup.

Fourth in sql server 2008 you can have ddl triggers which will tell you who changed the structure of a table not the data.